Is there a more optimized way to query with chained filters like: (a and b) or (c and d) or (e and f)
I have a table called cache.Geolocation, that has the amount of vehicles per city, given a VersionId and Year. It contains about 12 million rows. The format is as follows:

Now, I need to query it for a given set of vehicles (each vehicle is identified by a versionId and a year).
The query is something like this:
select VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from cache.Geolocation where 
    (VersionId = 175 and Year in (1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 176 and Year in (1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)) or 
    (VersionId = 177 and Year in (1998)) or 
    (VersionId = 178 and Year in (1995,1996)) or 
    (VersionId = 180 and Year in (1997,1998,1999)) or ....

And I have the following index:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Geolocation_Version_Year] ON [cache].[Geolocation]
(
    [VersionId] ASC,
    [Year] ASC
)
INCLUDE([CityId],[Count])

This takes almost 30 seconds to run. Is there a better query, or a better index, or a better way to organize this data, to be able to query faster?

Test the variant .. WHERE (VersionId, Year) IN ((175, 1999), (175, 2000), (176, 1996), ..) .. (if SQL Server accepts this, of course).

@Akina thanks for your comment, unfortunately this does not work (at lease on the Azure SQL).  I got the error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Yes, SQL Server does not implement row constructor, it produces Msg 4145 Level 15 State 1... Think about the next variant - save all separate pairs into temporary table, index it, then join it into your query.

Actual query plan would be helpful

As @rois suggests, the actual query plan would be really helpful.  How fast is the query with a single set of predicates?  I would expect that the optimizer would (at least consider) implementing this as a series of union all statements (i.e. select columns from table where versionId = 175 and year in (1999, 2000) union all select columns from table where versionId = 176 and year in (1996, ...)).  You could try rewriting it in that format to see if it helps.

I think the optimizer might offer a better plan by splitting each condition into the minimal AND fragments, and then OR them together.
To confirm this idea, I did some testing.
First, make table and index, then fill data, 600k rows.
CREATE TABLE Geolocation
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    VersionId int,
    [Year] int,
    CityId varchar(7),
    [Count] int, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Geolocation PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(id)
) 
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Geolocation_1 ON Geolocation
(
    VersionId ASC, [Year] ASC
)
INCLUDE (CityId, [Count])
GO

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @v INT
DECLARE @y INT
DECLARE @c INT
DECLARE @n INT

SET @i = 1
WHILE(@i<=600000) 
BEGIN
    SET @v= 100 + CAST(RAND()*100 AS INT)  -- 100 ~ 199
    SET @y= 1980 + CAST(RAND()*44 AS INT)  -- 1980 ~ 2023
    SET @c= 1000000 + CAST(RAND()*8000000 AS INT)  -- 1000000 ~ 8999999
    SET @n= 1 + CAST(RAND()*20 AS INT) -- 1 ~ 20

    INSERT INTO Geolocation (VersionId, [Year], CityId, [Count]) 
    VALUES
    (
        @v
        ,@y
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), @c)
        ,@n
    )
    SET @i+=1
END
GO

Then get execute plan and statistics information for each idea.
1. Guilherme's original SQL
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 175 and Year in (1999,2000)) or 
        (VersionId = 176 and Year in (1996,1997,1998,1999,2000)) or 
        (VersionId = 177 and Year in (1998)) or 
        (VersionId = 178 and Year in (1995,1996)) or 
        (VersionId = 180 and Year in (1997,1998,1999)) 

Statistics
(1778 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Geolocation'. Scan count 13, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 73 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

The plan is here
2. Use UNION ALL as @justin-cave suggested
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 175 and Year in (1999,2000))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 176 and Year in (1996,1997,1998,1999,2000))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 177 and Year in (1998))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 178 and Year in (1995,1996)) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        (VersionId = 180 and Year in (1997,1998,1999)) 

Statistics
(1778 rows affected)
Table 'Geolocation'. Scan count 13, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 71 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Plan

3. Use minimal logic fragments
    SELECT VersionId, Year, CityId, Count from Geolocation where 
        VersionId = 175 and Year = 1999 OR VersionId = 175 AND Year = 2000
        OR
        VersionId = 176 and Year = 1996 OR VersionId = 176 and Year = 1997 OR VersionId = 176 and Year = 1998 OR VersionId = 176 and Year = 1999 OR VersionId = 176 and Year = 2000
        OR
        VersionId = 177 and Year = 1998
        OR 
        VersionId = 178 and Year = 1995 OR VersionId = 178 and Year = 1996
        OR
        VersionId = 180 and Year = 1997 OR VersionId = 180 and Year = 1998 OR VersionId = 180 and Year = 1999

Statistics
(1778 rows affected)
Table 'Geolocation'. Scan count 13, logical reads 56, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 52 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

Plan

Summary
We can see, UNION ALL runs better, but very similarly with the original, elapsed time 71ms vs 73ms. It did not use HASH MATCH, because it has ALL clause, and need not temp table to do it(worktable).
By splitting each logic into minimal logic fragments, we get a very simple plan, one Index Seek gets it all. Look at the detail of it's Index Seek, it include every conditions we wrote. Index Seek of UNION ALL and the original, each Index Seek only contains conditions in that block. The optimizer is not smart as we wish.
This method uses less IO then others, logical reads 56 vs 66, because of less Index Seeks. And it cause better performance, elapsed time 52ms.
Theoretically, the method with minimal logic fragments has better performance. However, whether it can be used in practice depends on the complexity of the entire logic, it requires translating the logic that is clear in our minds into the way of writing mathematics.
I think the way to build index is already the best way, under the use case of your description.
